# Android App Bundle Update is not available

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

While migrating to the Andorid app bundle I have created the new App(i.e App1) and upload its apk to the internal testing in the play store. After that I have OptIn the Google Play Sign in and upload the .aab file to the play store with incrementing the version code. So the app is successfully uploaded in the play store with the same keystore that I have generated. But by sharing the app link to the testers, updated app shows in the play store with correct version but It Shows Open button instead of update. So do I have done something wrong in the Process?

Note: First build uploaded was an .apk extension after opt out explicitly and then opt in and upload .aab file to the internal testing in PlayStore

[image: ps://i.stack.imgur.com/merAW.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that can be at play (pun not intended):

- The testers have to opt in in receiving the internal testing version. The opt-in link is provided in the page where you configure the list of Testers. Until they opt-in, they won't receive the pre-release versions.
- After they opt-in, there is a propagation delay.
- The APK or AAB you upload must be approved by Play before it's released on tracks, which takes from a couple of hours to a few days as you probably already know. The internal testing track is different as in it usually doesn't require going through this validation step, but there's an exception for the first upload of an app which still needs to go though validation.

Note that this is not specific to App Bundles. It would be the same for APKs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my question is regarding the update of the build. e.g firstly I have release one build with 1.0 version and install it using the play store internal link, so there I see the build which I have uploaded with the same version. Then I again upload build with version say 1.1 and if I click on the previous link it will redirect to the store and and shows me updated version in more info i.e 1.1 but play store shows me open button instead of update button

Comment: For the refrence i have attached the screen shot in which updated build in the play store shows open button i.e 1.1 instead of update but in the about this app section it shows the updated version of the app

Comment: If the app info shows version 1.1 on your device, then it means the app has already been updated, in which case it makes sense to me that there is no update available in the Play Store. Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean to say the app shows version 1.1 on the play store info but on device app 1.0 is installed(i.e not update yet). Even if play store not giving option of the Update in internal testing(i.e even if updated version is on the play store)

Comment: Mhm, that seems like an impossible scenario. Could you share the screenshots showing 1.0 on the device and 1.1 on the Play store?

Comment: I have deleted the build now and promote it to Alpha channel. There are two possibilities. One is that I have uploaded the app bundle with different key but I am sure and I have rechecked that is fine. Second case is that there should be a bug in this special case from the play store side. So to verify it I have promote my 1.0 version to alpha channel and after review I will promote the 1.1 to alpha to see whether the Update is working or not

Comment: I think my problem is solved as I promote the build to the alpha channel. Now I am getting the update option. So may be some bug at google's end. Anyway Thanks!